# Do companies invite students to recruitment events that they have no intentions of hiring?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, internship

Sometimes I am invited to recruiting events from brand-name companies in my industry.  Such invites have been targeted, i.e. not just emailing every student in a major.

What does being invited to these events say about the chances of someone landing an internship there?

I'd like to clarify that I don't believe an invite is a guarantee of acceptance.  However, does such an invite at least guarantee that the company is interested, or are some students just invited to pad the numbers?

Comment: My guess is they invite as many people as they can so they can find the best candidates.  I don't think being invited to the recruitment events guarantees a position.  I think it just means you might have some skills they find valuable and they wanna see if you'd be a fit.

Comment: If you generalize the situation, aren't you really asking, "Would people in any workplace lie and inconvenience others to make themselves look good/busy?"  What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Students aren't invited "just to pass the numbers." Some might be invited even if the fit isn't obvious, on the theory that the students themselves probably have some idea of their potential value to the company... but really, the company doesn't want to waste time interviewing folks they know they won't accept. Remember, this process costs them real money; they don't want to waste it.